# When I install Trimmomatics_V0.32 through the command line on ubuntu LTS 14.04, I get an error

Tags: software-installation

Any one can suggest me best option for these problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is the wrong package name, it should just be `trimmomatic`

```
sudo apt-get install trimmomatic
```

Will install your package.